# No route matches {:controller=>"support", :action=>"/support"}

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

My code seems simple enough yet when I try the code below I get no route match error.

This is my controller

```
def support
end
```

This is my view

```
<%=  form_tag({ controller: "support",  action: "/support"}, method: "post")   do  %>
```

This is from running rake routes

```
root  /                  pages#index
contact  /contact(.:format) pages#contact
support  /support(.:format) pages#support
```

This is the error that I get

```
No route matches {:controller=>"support", :action=>"/support"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the routes, your controller is `pages` not `support`.

Comment: You should use named routes in your views whenever possible.  In this case, don't specify the controller and action; use `support_path`.